# Can a "thought" be alienable?

Tags: nouns

I have been doing some research around [Alienable and Inalienable Nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possession_(linguistics)#Alienable_and_inalienable), and it seems to me something like "a thought" could be considered an alienable noun.

'Alienable' here means something which can have its ownership transferred or not be owned at all. Clear examples are money or a shoe.

'Inalienable' is something that is nontransferable like say an attribute like someone's height or a parent.

The concept of "a thought" isn't necessarily owned by anyone, is it?. Is this correct?

Take the phrase "Now that's a thought.", would the thought in that sentence be considered alienable or inalienable?

---

An inalienable noun is something which A) cannot be transferred B) must be owned, and C) has an unbreakable relationship with the person who owns it. For example, your thoughts are inalienable because it's not possible for you to give them to someone else so that it is not yours anymore, and it's not possible for them to occur without you, the possessor.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135024/discussion-on-question-by-connor-can-a-thought-be-alienable).

Comment: Alienability is not a property of nouns, but of possession. You possess your body parts but you can't alienate them. You possess your bank account and you can alienate that. It's just a distinction that can be made about genitive/possessive constructions; some languages use different grammar for alienable vs not. In English we never notice, any more than we notice inclusive and exclusive 1st person plurals.

Comment: If your researched is based on an article, please cite it. Sometimes articles can be flawed and users may identify its weaknesses or simplifications. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possession_(linguistics)#Alienable_and_inalienable

Comment: 'We both had the same thought' and 'I really agree with a lot of "The Thoughts of Chairman Mao" ' really muddy the waters. 'Thought/s' is polysemous.

Comment: @JohnLawler Personally, I associate it with nouns, as the thing the noun represents defines if it is possessable or not.

Comment: Well, _thought_ is a noun, except when it's the past tense or past participle of _think_. But since it's immaterial, its possession is metaphorical, and that means you get to define its characteristics the way you like. So _a thought is alienable_ if that's the way you want it to be; or else _a thought is not alienable_, if **that's** the way you want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Syntactic Universals and Usage Frequency (MARTIN HASPELMATH, Leipzig Spring School on Linguistic Diversity, March 2008)](https://www.eva.mpg.de/lingua/conference/08_springschool/pdf/course_materials/Haspelmath_Possessives.pdf) is helpful if you accept it.

> 3. Alienable vs. inalienable possessive constructions
>
> 1 The main claim The universals of form-function relationship in alienability contrasts should not be explained in terms of iconic motivation, as in Haiman's (1983) influential paper, but by economic motivation and the frequency of occurrence in possessed constructions.

This seems reasonable to me and gives a quick and dirty test:

Is it "The X of Y (alienable) or Y’s X (inalienable)?” i.e. *The leg of the table v. the table’s leg* or *John's car or the car of John.*

Your example is "Now that's a thought." This  is an idiom that is understood as “That (What you have just said) is a good example of the result of the processes involved in thought.” And this would make “thought” alienable. NB, “suggestion” can be substituted for “thought”.

However, in “John’s thought is particularly relevant.” = “The suggestion that John made is particularly relevant.” makes “thought” inalienable.

It is worth adding that the paper makes this more complex and more accurate with

> alienability split = a possessive split determined by the possessum in which one of the classes characteristically consists of kinship terms and/or body part terms.

inalienable possessive construction = in an alienability split, a construction used with kinship and/or body part terms (and perhaps others)

> alienable possessive construction = in an alienability split, a construction not used with kinship and/or body part terms

Comment: What if a table is cannibalised and the legs used to make a different piece of furniture?

Comment: ... and can a table be said to "possess" anything material?

Comment: ... That one's easy. [Macmillan {1a}[(https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/possess): to have a quality or ability
_Kate is a woman who possesses a rare intelligence._ / 
_All these drugs possess sedative properties._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hmm... I don't think it is that easy... There's a little more to it than that - "sedative properties" is not material. A table may "possess" a patina, a history, stability, etc. but not a dog, a watch, or a car...

Comment: [Collins](): << VERB [no cont]
If someone or **something* possesses a particular quality, ability, or **feature**, they have it. >> ... 'The car possesses curvaceous and covered wheel arches with a low profile body for better aerodynamics of the vehicle.' [WorldAntiques ...](https://ar.pinterest.com/pin/7881368068767745/?amp_client_id=CLIENT_ID(_)&mweb_unauth_id=%7B%7Bdefault.session%7D%7D&simplified=true) / 'This means that the computer possesses a single processor' etc.

Comment: Wouldn't you still say, in the example "John's car", that the car was alienable from John?

Answer (score 1):

- The grammar of the English language doesn't depend on the concept of inalienable when forming modifiers from nouns, so the idea is only relevant in the context of a particular language that does use it (see the linked references).
- Some concepts apply under some circumstances and not under others. So it is certainly possible that a word could be alienable under one context, but not at all alienable in another circumstance.
- A 'thought', like for example when someone is thinking in their head "I'd like a bacon and egg sandwich.", seems to be pretty inalienable. It is entirely their thought, a biochemical event of neurons in the brain. Sure, you can convert that feeling into tongue and lung actions to push your thoughts into someone else's head, to reproduce that event in another similarly constructed meat bag. You've shared the thought with someone else. But the original event of thinking is your and yours alone.
- But a 'thought' considered as a general disembodied concept is certainly an alienable thing. It's not stuck with one person but is sort of out there separate from individuals. -That- kind of thought is alienable.

-If- English had grammar that depended on inalienability, then 'thought' could be alienable in one context, and not in another.

So the answer is... it depends.